# Regex Para Campos numericos

Tags: regex, validação

Preciso de um regex que valide números, virgulas, e ponto
ele deve conter números e se conter ponto ou virgula, tenha apenas um dos dois, e apenas uma vez

1.1 - true 
1,2 - true 
2 - true 
1..2 - false 
1.2. - false 
1,2.2 - false 
2,3,2 - false 
-2 - false 
,2 - false 
2, - false

com essa expressão '/[^0-9,.]/g' ela bloqueia qualquer coisa q não seja numeros pontos ou virgulas, mas vc pode colocar quantas vezes quiser(os pontos e virgulas).

Comment: Ok. O que fez? Qual foi o resultado obtido? Você sabe como elaborar uma expressão regular?

Comment: preciso de um regex q faça isso, sei apenas o basico sobre elaborar regex.

Comment: Então veja com o básico que possui e tente fazer antes. Se quiser testar, aconselho usar sites como o https://regex101.com/. Se ainda não conseguir, pode voltar aqui e [edit] a pergunta, adicionando a sua tentativa e qual foi o resultado obtido. Também recomendo que adicione todos os casos possíveis na sua descrição, pois não fica claro se `,1` seria um valor válido (mesmo possuindo números e apenas uma vírgula), ou `1,`.

Answer (score 0):

Quando colocada aqui uma pergunta, é suposto já termos algo para nos guiar. Mesmo assim, penso que será esta a solução.
Dígitos de 1 a 9 seguidos de um ponto ou vírgula com 1 número ou mais como casas decimais.

```
^[1-9]\d*(,\d+)?$   ----> para ,
^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$  ----> para .
```